# FourSquare hard coded Authentication on microcontroller

Tags: authentication, foursquare

I want to be able to check in to foursquare from a microcontroller. Now as it doesn't have a browser I can't use OAuth that allows user to accept the authorisation. 
Is there anyway I can hardcode this into the microcontroller code.

Basically I only want to be able to check in to a fixed place when I press a button on my embedded device to my own foursquare account. so it's a pretty static task.

any suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate your own OAuth token on the web and then hard-code the token + venueId into the device.

Comment: I ended up doing that. but isn't there any other way? to do it all on the device?

Comment: No, the OAuth flow requires a device capable of rendering a web page.